# Conditional Comments rendered on the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, conditional-comments

I am trying to add conditional comments to handle IE8 while using bootstrap 3. However, the conditional comments ends up being rendred if I try to display the page on IE8. What am I doing wrong?

This is how am defining the comments:

```
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Even if you weren't on `IE8` or not, the conditionals they wouldn't "disappear" or "render", they would appear just as you've written them. To check if that's working, look at the network tab to see if the relevant `.js.` are being collected (HTTP 200 etc)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. The code is supposed to be rendered on IE browsers of 8 and below. That's how it works.

Here's my Bootstrap 3 code for reference:

```
    <!-- media-queries.js (fallback) -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>            
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- html5.js and Respond-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
       <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```